# Using Watin in web app does not work on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, watin

I am trying to webscrape neteller account balance from web app ASP.NET MVC, IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 using WatiN's IE instance. My app works fine on local Windows 7, IIS, IE11, but on server 2008 with IE10, it seems that it can't type text in form and/or click on submit, when site is https.
When testing http site, typing search string and clicking on submit button works fine.
App pool identity is set to Local System, by experimenting. I disabled IE enhanced security, but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated, because I'm finished with ideas. Only workaround I thought about is script in powershell, running periodically and writing balance somewhere to database, and web app which will get balance from database.

Comment: I haven't had issues running Watin on windows server so unless it's something VERY specific to that web page (like clicking somewhere else before you are able to type the login information, etc.) I would debug it remotely to see what's going on exactly.